# How can Remove the specified permissions for SMS, from app’s manifest for an Ionic 3 Android APP

Tags: ionic3, sendmessage

I've developed for a client an Ionic 3 app that sends informative text messages - SMS to clients.
For this app I received  the following Google Play  warning:

" *Hello Google Play Developer,*
*In October, we [announced updates](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AEM7UVQF71XGH4hNaWveouwq7pUb0g1gJSAX-3gdgfhhxGy7etYirdoPh-MlHFl3YVGmz2lAj2E_va9resndXWsnpw_TYzir_pPjLQ8_UP2I_yAFad4h7WP8m6CVyqO9YHbCYaW7UEGYdzvgMTG8q9-GQ8aAJbQ0ckbUua7QOH3AWw) to our Permissions policy that will limit which apps are allowed to request Call Log and SMS permissions. **This is the second notification to let you know that this policy may impact one or more of your apps.***

*Only an app that has been selected as a user's default app for making calls or text messages, or whose core functionality is approved for one of the exception use cases, will be able to access Call Log or SMS permissions.*

*Below, we've listed a sample of apps from your catalog which may not meet the requirements for permission requests.*

***Action required***

*Please read through the [Permissions](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AEM7UVRjv90LArxyn0cpf_2eUwo3XpmIifzGZg4R4QN_tm3boV6WE1s79qWkM4JJnn9tY-SHbtPpF_HO3N_mj_ZDO84WqkwEwy3XYXUtHHost_0LVVmB5ErfyEeYEDy1Y9EyM3yOOoMM9hqP) policy and the [Play Console Help Center article](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AEM7UVR7U4dOxtW5457J5w6UgixHhyTiXAGIVnj7s6-FjfOvYSSS-sRqkUOovdv5PJ0k84qlN16SmWErEGT3vS1d4Hw-remnV3vW8DfUyO6-75Q33fWcoesExcVd8foT84oyu_YDwdCfVen4yg), which describes intended uses, exceptions, invalid uses, and alternative options for use of Call Log or SMS permissions, to determine which of the following options apply to your affected app(s):*

** **Option 1) Your app does not require access to Call Log or SMS permissions:** Remove the specified permissions from your app's manifest, or migrate to an [alternative implementation](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AEM7UVR7U4dOxtW5457J5w6UgixHhyTiXAGIVnj7s6-FjfOvYSSS-sRqkUOovdv5PJ0k84qlN16SmWErEGT3vS1d4Hw-remnV3vW8DfUyO6-75Q33fWcoesExcVd8foT84oyu_YDwdCfVen4yg) by **January 9, 2019** . If you require additional time to remove permissions or migrate to an alternative option, submit a [Permissions Declaration Form](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AEM7UVT5sX88p257W3oIOVFnSLyq2rj4C5MUCXnB22gIAz4fETr_NSVCiIJGPApk5cUXc2HhO1_vOnPp-XDH2ucxlF-Ge54Egpu88uhKUcdqnhaCWiLaloS5lGegFw3N2eOHRiQntYl5JJ3iPFYBiUVdQ_W9lPiOlpFd5IMJriStZZ0feKsjPRY6) to request an extension until March 9, 2019.*

** **Option 2) Your app is a default handler, or you believe your app qualifies for an exception:** If you haven't already done so, submit a request using the [Permissions Declaration Form](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AEM7UVT5sX88p257W3oIOVFnSLyq2rj4C5MUCXnB22gIAz4fETr_NSVCiIJGPApk5cUXc2HhO1_vOnPp-XDH2ucxlF-Ge54Egpu88uhKUcdqnhaCWiLaloS5lGegFw3N2eOHRiQntYl5JJ3iPFYBiUVdQ_W9lPiOlpFd5IMJriStZZ0feKsjPRY6) by **January 9, 2019** . We are currently reviewing submissions and will respond to your request. *Note: You do not need to make changes to your app in order to be eligible to submit a request.**"

It seems that the solution would be " **Option 1) Your app does not require access to Call Log or SMS permissions:** Remove the specified permissions from your app's manifest."
But I don't understand what to do. Where should I change and what? Should I modify my **config.xml** or the way I use **this.sms.send()** ? Or something else?

In my app I use SMS Plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms/)

To send the text messages I use a vector and call for each element the sms.send();

```
  for(var i=0;i<this.v_sms_complet.length;i++){
                if (this.v_sms_complet[i].CHECK_OK==true){
                         v_only_idsms_checked.push(this.v_sms_complet[i].id_sms);

                          //send sms
                          this.sms.send(this.v_sms_complet[i].phone, this.v_sms_complet[i].text_sms);
                          this.sleep(0.5);//0.5 second pause after each sms
                }
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Eventful, Before running the loop to send number of message you have to allow users to get permission. Follow the link to install plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions. If you face problem  try with @4.20.0 of android permission.  use  the code below 

this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.SEND_SMS).then(
            result => console.log('Has permission?',result.hasPermission),
            err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.SEND_SMS); 

Check next comment also.........

Comment: this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.SEND_SMS, this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_SMS]).then(()=>{
 
            var options = {
                replaceLineBreaks: false, default
                android: {
                    intent: ''   
                }
            }; 
            this.sms.send('01745439796','test sms', options); 
          });


Do not forget to use permission to android.manifest .. code below..
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />